# Google Cloud Platform renewed SSL cert stops app from serving

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, google-cloud-platform

Our GAE app has been serving from a custom domain for a year, using a GoDaddy SSL certificate that we uploaded a year ago. A few days ago they sent me an email saying we needed to renew it, so I did, and then I received an email on how to download it. They offered various server type choices, and since none were GAE, I chose "Other".

Next I tried to follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#obtaining_a_certificate, the section "Obtaining a Certificate". (I started with https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-google-app-engine.htm, but that seemed useless to me because I have a Mac, not a PC).

The instructions under "Obtaining a Certificate" don't explicitly describe renewal. I was pretty sure I shouldn't create a new CSR, since I have to assume the renewal cert used my old CSR given that GoDaddy didn't ask for a new CSR. But I had saved the files from a year ago when I obtained the original cert.

So jumping to step 5, I proceeded as follows:

- I unzipped the renewal certificate ZIP file I had obtained from GoDaddy.
- I had already done step 6 a year ago and still had that file, so I skipped step 6.
- I concatenated the CRT files from the renewal cert that had been inside the ZIP file.
- I went to the "SSL" link in step 7. On that page:

  - I used the "Upload a new certificate" link, sending the two required files.
  - I tried pointing my browser to the domain, and it returned a warning page that that page was unsafe because the certificate was out of date.
  - So I deleted the old certificate.
  - Again I tried going to my domain, and now I'm getting a page that says "This webpage is not available." Presumably all the users of my app are getting that as well.  :0(
- I also used the "To verify that the private key and certificate match..." steps under "Obtaining a Certificate" and the two hex values matched.

I've tried a variety of online searches without finding anything that addresses my issue. I'm sorry if it's out there, but I couldn't find it. Anyone know how I can get my app serving again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given in step 6 of a different section on the same page of my first link. After I had done everything else I described above, I still needed to do the following:

1. Click the name of the new certificate, which takes you to a new page.
2. Click the name of the domain.
3. Click Save.

None of this info appears on the SSL page, and the name you assigned to the uploaded certificate doesn't look like a link, but it is.